# Windows Authentication together with Asp.net MVC SimpleMembership?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, windows-authentication, simplemembership

I am developing a new Asp.net MVC web site using SimpleMembership Provider for protecting personalized pages.
The site run at Windows Server 2012.
I want to test the personalized pages as a logged in member but i don't want the site to be open to the public domain.

When i disable Anonymous Authentication and enable Windows Authentication, after i login with my Windows User Account Credentials the server respond with:

**No user found was found that has the name "COMPUTERNAME\username".**

```
[InvalidOperationException: No user found was found that has the name "COMPUTERNAME\username".]
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) +357
   System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +12404737
   CapitalMvc.MvcApplication.Application_PostAuthorizeRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +69
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +80
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
```

The question is then how can i use Windows Authentication in order to make the site visible only to me (inaccessible from public domain) and in the same time use SimpleMembership for testing the personalized pages that require SimpleMembership?
Is such a think possible without changing the code in my web app?

**Edit 1**
(These are the settings that i have in IIS Manager Authentication Section)
[image]

Comment: IE will automically use pass through authentication to log you in. If you want to access the site without without authentication, just use another browser like firefox or chrome.

Comment: I will try to clarify more what i want to do.
What i want to accomplish is when a user writes at the address bar "develop.mydomain.com" i want the Windows Authentication to kick in and when he enters valid credentials then he should navigate in the web site as anonymous user. Then when he requests a page that requires authorization he should be redirected in the login page.
This is required only during development in order to avoid spying eyes.

Comment: in iis settings could you please try disable anonymous access? I don't have iis 7.5 I have iis 6. right click your application in iis, select directory security tab, click edit, untick enable anonymous access.

Comment: Yes i have already done this. Please refer to the updated edit section in my original question.

Comment: when you type the url in browser, can you see the website or is it error you out straight away?

Comment: When i type the url the Windows Authentication kicks in and i get the popup login window. I enter the User Credentials that i have already setup in iis (local iis user account with full access in the website).
Then i get the error that i described in my initial post.